# XMPP's IQ exchange between clients with Strophe

Tags: javascript, xmpp, strophe

So I have 2 browsers running, both with the same page. In this page you can log into the server with an account.

The connection is build with Strophe. And everything is HTML and javascript.

Now I already managed to build a chat (between the 2 browsers, each logged in with a different user). And this is working perfectly.

What I want to achieve now is to send an IQ to one user from the other. Both saying in the status bar that they are receiving the IQ (one as a 'got the request', the other as 'got the result')

Now, I create my iq with:

```
    var iq = $iq({type: 'get', to: this.receiver}).c('query', {xmlns: 'http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#retrieve-subscriptions'});
    XmppObject.xmpp.connection.sendIQ(iq);
```

This is set in a function that can be called by the press of a button.
The listener is build as follow:

```
    $(XmppObject.xmpp).bind("iq", function(event, data){
    addToStatus('Received an iq: \n');
    handlePong(data.iq);
});
```

With handlePong as:

```
    function handlePong(msg)
{
    var objMsg = $(msg);
    var from = objMsg.attr('from');
    var type = objMsg.attr('type');
    var id = objMsg.attr('id');
    var text = 'Received iq from ' + from + ' with id ' + id + ' and type ' + type + '\n\n';
    addToStatus(text);
}
```

Now when client1 sends an IQ to client2 this is the result:

Client1:
`Received iq from client2@domain with id pingPong and type result`

Client2:

Now is there a way to display in the status of client2 that he got the initial request?

Comment: Man there are so many things that are plain wrong with your code that I do not know where to start. Do you *really* get a response that the other client received the iq, cause he shouldn't have...

Comment: I, also, do not really understand the question. What are the roles of client1 and client2? What do you mean on your final line by "initial request"?

Comment: @ggozad: wow, is it really that bad? These are just snippets though with which I hoped to show it. Aside from that it is also a prototype and not the final version. To answer the other question: yes, client1 receives the result IQ (type:result).

Comment: @MattJ : Client1 sends an IQ to client2. Client2 then send the result IQ. This part works. But client2 does not say he got the request from client1.
Hope this makes it a bit more clear on the goal.

Comment: @Kenneth No offense but let me list some ;) You initially send a PubSub subscriptions iq to the client. This must be some random copy paste. Then you pass the `xmpp` object to jQuery... Why? What is DOM binding have to do with iq handling? Finally instead of replying to the iq, you send a message? You need to better understand what you are trying to achieve and how XMPP and strophe and jQuery work.

Comment: @ggozad: None taken :) The PubSub was indeed wrong, just to test. In our XmppClient.js we have the IQ handling, this is to catch that. The message that you see is not an answer to the IQ, this is put on the webpage in the status window to let us know what we received. In a way I know what it does, it is just that I got this assignment from a colleague so not 100% into XMPP :)

Comment: @ggozad It's actually quite possible to use jQuery on XML stanzas in Javascript, because they are in fact DOM elements. Much nicer than using the raw DOM API.

Comment: @MattJ to *parse* stanzas with jQuery is great. To register handlers I would use Strophe's api that's what it's for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to:

- Construct an `iq` with you own namespace, you cannot just simply recycle the existing ones. It will work, but it's plain wrong.
- Add a handler on Strophe's connection to handle this type if iq. You do not do that by using jQuery's bind. You should use the `addHandler` on the connection.

The simplest example I can find doing exactly that is the `ping` implementation of strophe plugins, see https://github.com/metajack/strophejs-plugins/blob/master/ping/strophe.ping.js

Comment: I'm sorry, client2 is still not giving a sign that he is sending back a result IQ or that he even got the IQ

Comment: Rewriting and will try again.

Comment: This is what I receive: 
    RECV: <body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind'><iq xmlns='jabber:client' from='client1@domain' to='client2@domain/138673974513332025296815' type='error' id='9848:ping'><ping xmlns='object:xmpp:ping'/><error code='503' type='cancel'><service-unavailable xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'/></error></iq></body>

Comment: K, got it working, apparantly you really need to add a source ;) Thanks for the help @ggozad